# Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a set with an associative operation. Show that the following two Axioms are equivalent

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, associativity

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a set with an associative operation. Show that the following two Axioms are equivalent:

(a) : there exists a left-hand neutral element $e'$, so that $\forall a \in G: e'a=a$

(b): There exists a neutral element $e$, so that $\forall a\in G:ea=ae=a$

---

**My attempt:**

$(a)\Longrightarrow (b) :$

Let $e'$ be the left-hand inverse on $(G,\cdot)$.

Now let's take $a,b \in G$:

$$ab=a(e'b)=(ae')b=ab.$$

So in order for the associativity on $(G,\cdot)$ to hold, $e'$ has to be right-hand neutral as well.

$(b) \Longrightarrow (a):$

Is obvious ?

---

Is this correct? I mean, its quit obvious, thats why I suspect myself jumping to conclusions..

Comment: Your proof doesn't work since $ab=ac$ doesn't imply $b=c$ without inverses.

Comment: But if its not true, the operation cannot be called associative, or? And this was given

Comment: $B\implies A$ is obvious.  But it doesn't hurt to say let $e' = e$ then $e'a = ea = a$.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica I don't see why an associative operation needs to satisfy $ab=ac\to b=c$.

Comment: "e′ has to be right-hand neutral aswell."  No it doesn't.  $ab = (ae')b \not \implies a=ae'$

Comment: Okey I thought: $ab=a(e'b)$ is the same. But now associativity allows me to first calculate: $(ae')b$ and this has to be the same, which says $ae'=a$

Comment: @CoffeeArabica How does $ae'b=ab$ imply $e'b=b$?

Comment: "But if its not true, the operation cannot be called associative"  Why not?  If not that is *exactly* what you must prove.  There is *nothing* in associativity that says if $(a)b = (am)b$ then $a = am$.

Comment: oh okey :) thanks for the feedback. Ill look over it and sort my mind

Comment: Associativtity *DOES* say $ab = a(e'b) = (ae')b$ and I give you credit for doing that which is indeed the gyst of the matter but $(ae')b = ab$ doesn't mean $(ae') = a$ unless you can prove it.  Consider $7*0 = 7*(2*0) = (7*2) *0$ so does that mean $7$ has to equal $7*2$?

Comment: To go  $ab = cb \implies a=c$ is to assume right cancelation. Which you don't have.  Another way is look at it is it assumes that operation is invertible.  In terms of function this presumes the operation in one to one or injective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two statements are not equivalent. Although (b) implies (a), it is not the case that (a) implies (b).

To verify this, let $G=\{e,a\}$, and define the operation as follows: $ea=a$, $aa=a$, $ae=e$, $ee=e$. That is, the result of multiplying $x$ by $y$ is always $y$.

This is easily seen to be associative, since $x(yz) = yz = z$ and $(xy)z=z$.

It is also clear that both $e$ and $a$ are left inverses, since $ee=e$, $ea=a$ (and also $ae=e$ and $aa=a$). However, neither $e$ nor $a$ are two-sided inverses.

The flaw in your attempt, as has been pointed out, is that associativity does not imply cancellativity. You cannot go from $xy=xz$ to $y=z$, or from $xy=zy$ to $x=z$, from just knowing the operation is associative. But that is what you are attempting to do when claiming that $(ae’)b = ab$ requires $ae’=a$.

Comment: Very nice and straightforward counterexample, @Arturo!

Comment: *VERY* nice counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

As Arturo Magidin answer shows $A\not \implies B$.

Perhaps you were supposed to have A) be that there is a left inverse and a (potentially different[1]) right identity:

That is

A) There exists $e', e’’$ so that $e'a = a$ for all $a$ and $be’’ = b$ for all $b$.

If that is true

Claim:  $e'= e"$.

Pf:   $e'e’’ = e'$ by definition of $e'$.  And $e'e’’= e’’$ by definition $e' =e'e’’ = e’’$.

Thus $e'a = a = ae’’ = ae'$ for all $a$ so $B$ is implied.

$A\implies B$.

And as you say $B \implies A$ is obvious (just let $e' = e$ and $e’’ = e$.)

====

[1] hypothetically potentially different, but as we prove, not actually possible to be different.

Comment: MathJax gets confused with `”`; for a double prime, you have to use `’’`.

Comment: One way to phrase your footnote 1 which is slightly more common is to say they are “not necessarily equal to one another”.